# Does Aria support the MVCC transaction level?

Tags: mariadb

As subject says - I can't find this information in the documentation so I am assuming it does not (support the MVCC). Can someone point out some article or document which clearly answers the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Aria is not really transactional. Except that all writes are atomic, so they completely succeed or completely fail.